# using pre tag for the img code

Tags: html

hi guys i am trying to use a pre tag for this code.
But i am unable to get results. all i see is blank screen.

text to be added

```
    <img src="" 
data-desk="img/single/desktop.jpg" 
data-lap="img/single/laptop.jpg"
data-tab="img/single/ipad.jpg" />
```

i just did this but notehing happens

```
 <pre>
    <code>  <img src="" 
      data-desk="img/single/desktop.jpg" 
      data-lap="img/single/laptop.jpg"
      data-tab="img/single/ipad.jpg" /></code>
    </pre>
```

Somehow it takes img as tag rather than a pre ..
Please help.thanks.

Comment: Escape the `<` and use it as `&lt;` instead. That should be enough (not tested, but should work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this..

```
<pre>&lt;img src="foo.jpg",
 data-desk="fooDesk"
  data-lap="fooLap" /&gt;</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should encode you code and then put it in `pre` tag. use [Online Encoder](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/DotNet/Tools/HTMLEncode/Encode.aspx) or if you are a C# programmer use `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(str);` or javascript `encodeURI(str);`

```
<pre>
  &lt;img src=&quot;&quot; 
  data-desk=&quot;img/single/desktop.jpg&quot; 
  data-lap=&quot;img/single/laptop.jpg&quot;
  data-tab=&quot;img/single/ipad.jpg&quot; /&gt;
</pre>
```

Comment: I don't think you were supposed to escape the `code` tags, and the `&quot;`'s are unnecessary clutter.

Comment: @NisseEngström I see...